# How can I determine whether an arc is clockwise or anti-clockwise?

Tags: geometry

I have 3 points on an Arc - Start, MidPoint & EndPoint.

I also know the Radius and the Center.

How can I determine whether an arc is clockwise or anti-clockwise relative to it's Center?

Comment: I would say that it can be both. However if somebody lists the points S,M,E then it clockwise, as opposed to listing the points this wax: E,M,S then it is counterclockwise.

Answer (score 4):

Let ${\bf s}=(s_1,s_2)$, ${\bf m}=(m_1,m_2)$, ${\bf e}=(e_1,e_2)$ be the three points. We have to check whether the triangle they form is positively oriented. Therefore compute the quantity
$$\sigma:=({\bf m}-{\bf s})\wedge({\bf e}-{\bf s})=(m_1-s_1)(e_2-s_2)-(m_2-s_2)(e_1-s_1)\ .$$
If $\sigma>0$ the arc is counterclockwise, if $\sigma<0$ the arc is clockwise.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it, assuming you know the Cartesian co-ordinates, x and y, of the start and end point:

direction = ( ( ( arctan(y1/x1) - arctan(y2/x2) ) > 0 ) ? clockwise : anti-clockwise

Comment: Oops, one bracket too many on the far left side :/